# How to mock Stripe classes in PHP Codeception

Tags: yii2, phpunit, stripe-payments, codeception

I am trying to mock a simple Stripe\Customer instance in a unit test.  The method only uses this instance to retrieve the name property.  In my test, the **make** statement looks like this:

```
$customer = $this->makeEmpty(Customer::class, ['name' => $cust_nm]);
```

Codeception returns the following error:

> Could not add property name, class Stripe\Customer implements __set
> method, and no name property exists

I have also tried to use **makeEmptyExcept** but get the same error message.  All I really want is to pass the object to a method and pull a property or two.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't mock it, simply create an instance and set a property.

```
$customer = new Customer();
$customer->name = $cust_nm;
```

Comment: Thanks.  That's what ended up doing after all.